# <select> não funcionando corretamente

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou enfrentando um problema, do qual não achei tutoriais claros o suficiente na internet para que eu pudesse aprender a como solucionar, que aparentemente parece ser simples mas não estou conseguindo resolver. O problema consiste em fazer com que o `<select>` desça somente quando clicar nele. Porém, quando eu clico em 1, os 3 descem:[image: select dropdown]

Como no código abaixo, eu tentei mudar a  `class` para `drop1,drop2`. Alterei também no .css e no .Js, mas tenho certeza que fiz algo errado, só não sei onde.

**Style.css:**

```
body {
  background: #35414a;
}

.drop {
  width: 20em;
  margin: 5em auto;
  font-family: pfs-bold;
  color: #86919a;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.5s;
  transition: width 0.5s;
  will-change: width;
}
.drop .option {
  padding: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #333333;
}
.drop .option:not(.active) {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
          transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.drop.visible {
  -webkit-animation: bounce 1s;
          animation: bounce 1s;
  width: 24em;
}
.drop.visible:before, .drop.visible:after {
  border-color: #fff;
}
.drop.visible:before {
  opacity: 0;
}
.drop.visible:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
.drop.visible .option {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
}
.drop.opacity .option {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
          transform: translateZ(0);
  opacity: 1;
}
.drop.opacity .option:nth-child(0) {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s 0s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0s, transform 0.5s 0s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0s, transform 0.5s 0s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0s;
}
.drop.opacity .option:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s 0.1s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.1s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.1s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.1s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.1s, transform 0.5s 0.1s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.1s, transform 0.5s 0.1s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.1s;
}
.drop.opacity .option:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s 0.2s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.2s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.2s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.2s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.2s, transform 0.5s 0.2s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.2s, transform 0.5s 0.2s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.2s;
}
.drop.opacity .option:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.3s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.3s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.3s, transform 0.5s 0.3s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.3s, transform 0.5s 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.3s;
}
.drop.opacity .option:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s 0.4s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.4s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.4s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.4s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.4s, transform 0.5s 0.4s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.4s, transform 0.5s 0.4s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.4s;
}
.drop.opacity .option:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.5s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.5s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.5s, transform 0.5s 0.5s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.5s, transform 0.5s 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.5s;
}
.drop.opacity .option:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s 0.6s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.6s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.6s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.6s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.6s, transform 0.5s 0.6s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.6s, transform 0.5s 0.6s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.6s;
}
.drop.opacity .option:nth-child(7) {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s 0.7s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.7s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.7s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.7s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.7s, transform 0.5s 0.7s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.7s, transform 0.5s 0.7s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.7s;
}
.drop.opacity .option:nth-child(8) {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s 0.8s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.8s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.8s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.8s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.8s, transform 0.5s 0.8s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.8s, transform 0.5s 0.8s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.8s;
}
.drop.opacity .option:nth-child(9) {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s 0.9s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.9s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.9s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.9s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.9s, transform 0.5s 0.9s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.9s, transform 0.5s 0.9s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.9s;
}
.drop.withBG .option {
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.1s;
  transition: background-color 0.1s;
}
.drop.withBG .option:not(.placeholder):hover {
  background-color: #5aafee;
}
.drop.withBG .option:not(.placeholder).active {
  background-color: #5aafee;
}
.drop:after, .drop:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.5em;
  right: 1em;
  width: 0.75em;
  height: 0.75em;
  border: 0.2em solid #86919a;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
          transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
          transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
.drop:before {
  border-left: none;
  border-top: none;
  top: 1.2em;
}
.drop:after {
  border-right: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  opacity: 0;
}

.mini-hack {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
          transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

**script.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".drop .option").click(function() {
    var val = $(this).attr("data-value"),
        $drop = $(".drop"),
        prevActive = $(".drop .option.active").attr("data-value"),
        options = $(".drop .option").length;
    $drop.find(".option.active").addClass("mini-hack");
    $drop.toggleClass("visible");
    $drop.removeClass("withBG");
    $(this).css("top");
    $drop.toggleClass("opacity");
    $(".mini-hack").removeClass("mini-hack");
    if ($drop.hasClass("visible")) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $drop.addClass("withBG");
      }, 400 + options*100); 
    }
    triggerAnimation();
    if (val !== "placeholder" || prevActive === "placeholder") {
      $(".drop .option").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
    };
  });

  function triggerAnimation() {
    var finalWidth = $(".drop").hasClass("visible") ? 22 : 20;
    $(".drop").css("width", "24em");
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".drop").css("width", finalWidth + "em");
    }, 400);
  }
});
```

**index.html**

```
<div class="drop">
  <div class="option active placeholder" data-value="placeholder">
    Escolha o Serviço
  </div>
  <div class="option" data-value="wow">
    Hour Boost
  </div>
  <div class="option" data-value="drop">
    Commend Bot
  </div>
  <div class="option" data-value="select">
    Report Bot
  </div>
</div>
                    <div class="drop1">
  <div class="option active placeholder" data-value="placeholder">
    Choose wiseely
  </div>
  <div class="option" data-value="wow">
    Wow!
  </div>
  <div class="option" data-value="drop">
    So dropdown!
  </div>
  <div class="option" data-value="select">
    Very select!
  </div>
  <div class="option" data-value="custom">
    Much custom!
  </div>
  <div class="option" data-value="animation"> 
    Such animation!
  </div>
</div>
                    <div class="drop2">
  <div class="option active placeholder" data-value="placeholder">
    Choose wisely
  </div>
  <div class="option" data-value="wow">
    Wow!
  </div>
  <div class="option" data-value="drop">
    So dropdown!
  </div>
  <div class="option" data-value="select">
    Very select!
  </div>
  <div class="option" data-value="custom">
    Much custom!
  </div>
  <div class="option" data-value="animation"> 
    Such animation!
  </div>
</div>
```

Segue exemplo no [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/atdd44tb/)

Comment: Testa trocar a variável `$drop = $(".drop")` por `$drop = $(this)` dentro da sua função de `click`.

Comment: @AndreGusmao `$drop = $(this).click(function() {` ainda infuncional, inclusive bugou o html http://prntscr.com/hhdt97

Comment: Você alterou no lugar errado. Seria aqui: `$(".drop .option").click(function() { var val = $(this).attr("data-value"), $drop = $(this); ...`

Comment: Não falta uma função de `click` no `$(".drop")`? Tem só a função de click no option do drop `$(".drop .option")`. A página já carrega com os drops aparecendo?

Comment: Não, eles só descem depois que são clicados.

Comment: Veja o meu terceiro comentário.

Comment: @AndreGusmao fiz essa alteração, porém nemhum dos 3 selects descem. É incrivel a complexidade de algo tão besta

Comment: Põe no Stack snippet ou no jsfiddle pra ficar mais fácil de testarmos

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Adicionei o link do Fiddle no rodapé da pergunta.

Comment: O problema parece ser no `triggerAnimation();`, ele esta disparando em todos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você consegue abrir cada menu pegando o index do que foi clicado, mas deixe todos os menus com a classe `drop` mesmo (e não `drop1`, `drop 2`...):

```
 mIdx = $(this).closest('.drop').index('.drop');
```

Também alterei as referências do `.drop` criando uma única variável `$drop` para toda a função, além de enviar essa variável à função `triggerAnimation()` que irá fazer a animação do menu.

**Veja funcionando:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".drop .option").click(function() {
    mIdx = $(this).closest('.drop').index('.drop');
    var val = $(this).attr("data-value"),
    $drop = $(".drop:eq("+mIdx+")"),
    prevActive = $drop.find(".option.active").attr("data-value"),
    options = $drop.find(".option").length;
    $drop.find(".option.active").addClass("mini-hack");
    $drop.toggleClass("visible");
    $drop.removeClass("withBG");
    $(this).css("top");
    $drop.toggleClass("opacity");
    $(".mini-hack").removeClass("mini-hack");
    if ($drop.hasClass("visible")) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $drop.addClass("withBG");
      }, 400 + options*100); 
    }
    triggerAnimation($drop);
    if (val !== "placeholder" || prevActive === "placeholder") {
      $drop.find(".option").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
    };
  });

  function triggerAnimation($drop) {
    var finalWidth = $drop.hasClass("visible") ? 22 : 20;
    $drop.css("width", "24em");
    setTimeout(function() {
      $drop.css("width", finalWidth + "em");
    }, 400);
  }
});
```

```css
@font-face {
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
body {
  background: #35414a;
}

.drop {
  width: 20em;
  margin: 5em auto;
  font-family: pfs-bold;
  color: #86919a;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.5s;
  transition: width 0.5s;
  will-change: width;
}
.drop .option {
  padding: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #333333;
}
.drop .option:not(.active) {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
          transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.drop.visible {
  -webkit-animation: bounce 1s;
          animation: bounce 1s;
  width: 24em;
}
.drop.visible:before, .drop.visible:after {
  border-color: #fff;
}
.drop.visible:before {
  opacity: 0;
}
.drop.visible:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
.drop.visible .option {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
}
.drop.opacity .option {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
          transform: translateZ(0);
  opacity: 1;
}
.drop.opacity .option:nth-child(0) {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s 0s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0s, transform 0.5s 0s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0s, transform 0.5s 0s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0s;
}
.drop.opacity .option:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s 0.1s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.1s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.1s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.1s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.1s, transform 0.5s 0.1s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.1s, transform 0.5s 0.1s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.1s;
}
.drop.opacity .option:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s 0.2s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.2s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.2s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.2s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.2s, transform 0.5s 0.2s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.2s, transform 0.5s 0.2s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.2s;
}
.drop.opacity .option:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.3s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.3s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.3s, transform 0.5s 0.3s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.3s, transform 0.5s 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.3s;
}
.drop.opacity .option:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s 0.4s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.4s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.4s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.4s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.4s, transform 0.5s 0.4s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.4s, transform 0.5s 0.4s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.4s;
}
.drop.opacity .option:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.5s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.5s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.5s, transform 0.5s 0.5s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.5s, transform 0.5s 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.5s;
}
.drop.opacity .option:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s 0.6s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.6s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.6s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.6s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.6s, transform 0.5s 0.6s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.6s, transform 0.5s 0.6s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.6s;
}
.drop.opacity .option:nth-child(7) {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s 0.7s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.7s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.7s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.7s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.7s, transform 0.5s 0.7s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.7s, transform 0.5s 0.7s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.7s;
}
.drop.opacity .option:nth-child(8) {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s 0.8s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.8s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.8s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.8s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.8s, transform 0.5s 0.8s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.8s, transform 0.5s 0.8s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.8s;
}
.drop.opacity .option:nth-child(9) {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s 0.9s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.9s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.9s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.9s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.9s, transform 0.5s 0.9s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.9s, transform 0.5s 0.9s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.9s;
}
.drop .option {
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.1s;
  transition: background-color 0.1s;
}
.drop .option:not(.placeholder):hover {
  background-color: #5aafee;
}
.drop .option:not(.placeholder).active {
  background-color: #5aafee;
  color: #fff;
}
.drop:after, .drop:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.5em;
  right: 1em;
  width: 0.75em;
  height: 0.75em;
  border: 0.2em solid #86919a;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
          transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
          transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
.drop:before {
  border-left: none;
  border-top: none;
  top: 1.2em;
}
.drop:after {
  border-right: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  opacity: 0;
}

.mini-hack {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
          transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/i18n/defaults-*.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
 
                <center><h4 style="color: white">Escolha o plano</h4>
<div class="drop">
  <div class="option active placeholder" data-value="placeholder">
    Escolha o Serviço
  </div>
  <div class="option" data-value="wow">
    Hour Boost
  </div>
  <div class="option" data-value="drop">
    Commend Bot
  </div>
  <div class="option" data-value="select">
    Report Bot
  </div>
</div>
                    <div class="drop">
  <div class="option active placeholder" data-value="placeholder">
    Choose wiseely
  </div>
  <div class="option" data-value="wow">
    Wow!
  </div>
  <div class="option" data-value="drop">
    So dropdown!
  </div>
  <div class="option" data-value="select">
    Very select!
  </div>
  <div class="option" data-value="custom">
    Much custom!
  </div>
  <div class="option" data-value="animation"> 
    Such animation!
  </div>
</div>
                    <div class="drop">
  <div class="option active placeholder" data-value="placeholder">
    Choose wisely
  </div>
  <div class="option" data-value="wow">
    Wow!
  </div>
  <div class="option" data-value="drop">
    So dropdown!
  </div>
  <div class="option" data-value="select">
    Very select!
  </div>
  <div class="option" data-value="custom">
    Much custom!
  </div>
  <div class="option" data-value="animation"> 
    Such animation!
  </div>
</div>
                </center>
```

Comment: Copiei exatamente os código do Fiddle, mas ainda assim, não funciona.
Eu clico em um select e desce o de baixo. E quando eu clico novamente, ele buga/some

Eu to começando a ficar pistola com isso

Comment: Adicionei no rodapé da pergunta o meu código no fiddle. Se você adicionar a sua resposta ao código vai ver exatamente oque está acontecendo.

Comment: Eu tava achando que era meu navegador kk vou aguardar.

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcinou perfeitamente.

Comment: Um outro bug que está ocorrendo é o `:focus` ele não marca a `option` corretamente, no proprio fiddle que tu fez dá pra perceber isso. Passe o mouse entre as opções do select e verá

Comment: Isso mesmo, em algumas opçoes não fica azul.
até tentei `.drop:focus{ color: red;}` para testar, mas não foi

Comment: @LucasRodrigues O problema tava no CSS que já consertei na resposta. Tinha uma referência `.drop.withBG` onde esse `.withBG` não existe, foi só apagar isso. E ainda coloquei uma `color: #fff;` pro texto ficar branco.

Comment: Caso eu queira mudar a cor do `focus`, qual *elemento(nao sei se é o nome certo)* eu teria que mudar?

Comment: Perdão, acabei de ver aqui `.drop .option:not(.placeholder):hover {background-color: #5aafee;` novamente, muito obrigado.